# Is there a way to put one column uner two columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'd like to have a structure like the one shown below.
[image: The red box indicates the window and the black boxes indicate the]
The red box indicates the window and the black boxes indicate the <div>.

I've tried my best to put the picture under two columns. However, I can't figure out how to have a div wrapping them without using the whole width of the screen.

Also, how do you make the right side blank? By adding a new blank div to occupy the space?

Comment: Please show your html with Bootstrap classes applied. The layout can be done easily by creating a [Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/) and adding content.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrapp description, toggle and image divs in a fixed-size div as parent. Then, you could use boostrap or CSS grid for generatig the desire behavior. Doing in this way, you don't need a blank div as you proposed, it's not necessary.

Check docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Answer (score 0):

You may need to tweak this to get the sizes you want but the basic idea is there.

```
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-10 m-4" style="border: 1px solid black">
      <div class="d-flex ml-2 mr-4 mt-4 mb-4">
        <div class="col-8 mr-2" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 50px;">Col 8</div>
      <div class="col-4" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 50px; margin-left: 12px;">Col 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ml-2 mr-1 mb-4">
      <div class="col-12" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 300px">Col 12</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```